# How to open a url with an IP in the background without any browser?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-studio

I have this code for android to open a url, but I can't make it to run in the background. Is it possible?
Can someone help me with this? Thanks.

```
public void goToSu (View view) {
        goToUrl("http://192.168.2.66/index.html?o0=0");
    }

    private void goToUrl (String url) {
        Uri uriUrl = Uri.parse(url);
        Intent background = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uriUrl);
        startActivity(background);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot make network operations in your main UI, because that would block your program execution with a very disgusting experience for your users. For this, you have to separate network operations inside a `Thread`, or even better, an `AsyncTask` if you're just starting with the thread world.

This is the structure you would use:

```
final class MyNetworkOperation extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Void> {
  @Override
  protected void onPreExecute(final Void param) {
    ...
  }

  @Override
  protected Void doInBackground(final URL... args) {
    ...
    return null;
  }

  @Override
  protected void onPostExecute(final Void param) {
    ...
  }
}
```

Even the method names are very self explanatory. When you define your AsyncTask, and call `.execute(url_object)` on it, the first called method will be `.onPreExecute()`, there you may initialize variables and prepare everything for the network operation you want to do. The *hard* part of your network operation should be done inside `doInBackground()`. There you connect, do the data transfer and disconnect from the host. Finally, `onPostExecute()` is called: Once you're done, you can process here your results (transfer it to the main Activity, show a Dialog, etc.).

For more on AsyncTasks (and know what does those parameters mean) I strongly recommend reading the [reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

A very good example might be found [here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html).

Comment: and what about if i want to make the process run on a click event?

Comment: There's nothing special with that, simply call `your_asyncthread_instance.execute()` within your `onClick()` method.

Comment: would i be able to use that on multiple buttons each with a different ip? or must i specificaly use the asynchthread on each button cuz my ip range goes fron 192.168..2.66/index.html?o0=0,0=1 all the way to 7=0, 7=1

Comment: You can use the same `AsyncThread` extension with an instance for each IP. You can then pass the IP into the `execute(ip)` method, and get them into the `doInBackground()` method. You have a nice example of that in the link I provided, have a look at how to pass parameters, once done it will work like a charm.

Comment: maybe im just being stupid, or over tired but i cant seam to get it to work.

Comment: If you're trying to do what you've posted in your question, you cannot do it that way. You cannot start `Activities` within `AsyncTasks` in the `doInBackground()` function. You can do, however, in the `onPostExecute()` task. Another way would be setting a `Handler` in your main `Activity` and send a `Message` through that `Handler` in your `AsyncTask`. In the last link I provided there's a very good example on this.